# Validate Elevated Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, visual-studio-code, calculator, tax

I'm making an app using Flutter which calculates motor vehicle tax.
[image]

It calculates it perfectly fine when I enter the cost of vehicle.
But I want to add a validation to it. When I don't enter any cost of vehicle and keeps it empty and then click the calculate button, I want it show - please enter the cost.
How do I add this validation as this is not a form.

Here is the code of that part:

```
TextField(
            controller: costController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Cost of Vehicle"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  toPrint = calc(
                    dropDownValue!,
                    int.parse(costController.text),
                  ).toString();
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Calculate")),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                )),
            child: Text("Tax :  $toPrint "),
          ),
```

Comment: Wrap it in a form and you can use all the regular validation methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the column with a Form widget add avalidator to the textfield

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: const MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: costController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Cost of Vehicle"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                setState(() {
                  toPrint = calc(
                    dropDownValue!,                    int.parse(costController.text),
                  ).toString();
                });
               }
              },
              child: const Text("Calculate")),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                )),
            child: Text("Tax :  $toPrint "),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked, also had to change TextField to TextFormField

Answer (score 1):

Use Form Widget and Convert TextField to TextFormField like that.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FormWidget> createState() => _FormWidgetState();
}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {

  final TextEditingController costController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _formKey,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Form(
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return "Please enter the cost.";
                }
                return null;
              },
              controller: costController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Cost of Vehicle"),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                  //do your setState stuff
                  setState(() {
                  });
                }

              },
              child: const Text("Calculate")),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                )),
            child: Text("Tax : "),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```